# Selenium cant locate element inside ::before ::after

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, pseudo-element

Element to be located

[image: Element to be located]

I am trying to locate a span element inside a webpage, I have tried by XPath but its raise timeout error, I want to locate title span element inside Facebook marketplace product. [url](https://www.facebook.com/marketplace/item/339217790895108/?ref=search&referral_code=marketplace_search&referral_story_type=post&tracking=browse_serp%3A4b8d02de-a5f4-4f73-9947-8447a25fdb32)

here is my code :

```
def title_detector():
    title = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
        EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, 'path'))).text
    list_data = title.split("ISBN", 1)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't locate pseudo elements with XPath, only with CSS selector.
I see it's FaceBook with it's ugly class names...
I'm not sure this will work for you, maybe these class names are dynamic, but it worked for me this time.
Anyway, the css_locator for that `span` element is `.dati1w0a.qt6c0cv9.hv4rvrfc.discj3wi .d2edcug0.hpfvmrgz.qv66sw1b.c1et5uql.lr9zc1uh.a8c37x1j.keod5gw0.nxhoafnm.aigsh9s9.qg6bub1s.fe6kdd0r.mau55g9w.c8b282yb.iv3no6db.o0t2es00.f530mmz5.hnhda86s.oo9gr5id`
So, since we are trying to get it's `before` we can do it with the following JavaScript script:

```
span_locator = `.dati1w0a.qt6c0cv9.hv4rvrfc.discj3wi .d2edcug0.hpfvmrgz.qv66sw1b.c1et5uql.lr9zc1uh.a8c37x1j.keod5gw0.nxhoafnm.aigsh9s9.qg6bub1s.fe6kdd0r.mau55g9w.c8b282yb.iv3no6db.o0t2es00.f530mmz5.hnhda86s.oo9gr5id`
script = "return window.getComputedStyle(document.querySelector('{}'),':before').getPropertyValue('content')".format(span_locator)
print(driver.execute_script(script).strip())
```

In case the css selector above not working since the class names are dynamic there - try to locate that `span` with some stable css_locator, it is possible. Just have to try it several times until you see which class names are stable and which are not.

UPD:
You don't need to locate the pseudo elements there, will be enough to catch that `span` itself. So, it will be enough something like this:

```
span_locator = `.dati1w0a.qt6c0cv9.hv4rvrfc.discj3wi .d2edcug0.hpfvmrgz.qv66sw1b.c1et5uql.lr9zc1uh.a8c37x1j.keod5gw0.nxhoafnm.aigsh9s9.qg6bub1s.fe6kdd0r.mau55g9w.c8b282yb.iv3no6db.o0t2es00.f530mmz5.hnhda86s.oo9gr5id`
def title_detector():
    title = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
        EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'span_locator'))).text
    title = title.strip()
    list_data = title.split("ISBN", 1)
```

Comment: i am sorry i only use xpath, id and class selectors, i attached a pic of the element can you check it out.

Comment: I'm trying to explain you that pseudo elements (after and before) can not be located by Selenium with XPath. It's not me.

Comment: no no i understood, its not necessary to use xpath, any selector that returns the element will do fine,

Comment: Please let me know if it helped?

Comment: hmm it didnt work for me, i get {error: Failed to execute 'getComputedStyle' on 'Window': parameter 1 is not of type 'Element'}, yes even tho the class seems dynamic i checked it in other products page and it seems to be the same. and wil this returns the text after the before: ?

Comment: I think you don't really need to deal with pseudo elements there.  Please try the updated answer

Comment: alright thanks for your help, i will give it a try .

Comment: alright i used one of the classes and found only 2 elements has it on the whole page, so my problem solved, should i accept your answer as solved ?

Answer (score 1):

Try this xpath  //span[contains(text(),'isbn')]

Comment: didnt work, i need something more dynamic